# Как сделать так, чтобы команда бота дискорд работала только при условии, что человек в голосовом чате (python)

Tags: python, discord, бот

пишу музыкального бота для дискорда и сейчас пишу ему основные команды. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы бот исполнял команды подобную нижеприведенной только если пользователь находится в одном голосовом чате с ним. Вопрос: как это реализовать? Я пытался сделать это ниже, но в итоге потом заметил, то что команда работает если пользователь будет в ЛЮБОМ войс чате. Вопрос: как это исправить и сделать так, чтобы бот реагировал только на команды человека, который с ним в одном войсе? Заранее спасибо

```py
@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    """Пропускает песню и начинает играть следующую в очереди"""
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=server)
    if not ctx.author.voice is None:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.stop()
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, ничего не воспроизводится')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, Вы должны находиться в голосовом канале, чтобы использовать эту команду')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def skip(ctx):
    """Пропускает песню и начинает играть следующую в очереди"""
    user = id бота
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=server)
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel == ctx.user.voice and ctx.user.voice.channel:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.stop()
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, ничего не воспроизводится')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, Вы должны находиться в голосовом канале, чтобы использовать эту команду')
```

я изменил `if not ctx.author.voice is None:` на     `if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel == ctx.user.voice and ctx.user.voice.channel:` и добавил `user = id bota`

По идее это должно вам помочь!